# Dislocations and Random Matrix Theory

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, calculus-of-variations, textbook-recommendation

Does anyone have a good reference book that works as a good starting point for an analyst to learn about the connection between *Random Matrix Theory* and *Dislocations*? Thank you for your help.

By *dislocations*, I mean those that are present in materials as defects in their crystalline structure. More specifically, dislocations that form grain boundaries.

A more precise question would be, is there literature outlining the way to describe dislocation distributions via random matrix theory?

Comment: What type of "dislocations" are you interested in? Vortices in superdconductors (as in https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.06287)? Singularities of complex wave fields (as in https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/30807.pdf). You really want to be more specific for a helpful answer.

Comment: Hi @CarloBeenakker, thank you for that remark. Yes, that makes sense. By dislocations, I mean those that form grain boundaries in materials.

Comment: thank you for the clarification; I am not aware of any application of that type; typical applications to RMT involve some sort of repulsion between the defects, which are then modeled by eigenvalue repulsion; I don't think that grain boundaries "repel" in any obvious way, because they are frozen and lack dynamics; perhaps you can inform us where the idea comes from, that RMT might be applicable to grain boundaries?

Comment: Not sure if RMT is applicable, but here's a work related spectral graph theory to grain boundary modeling: Johnson, Oliver K., Jarrod M. Lund, and Tyler R. Critchfield. "Spectral graph theory for characterization and homogenization of grain boundary networks." Acta Materialia 146 (2018): 42-54.